# CSS3 opacity property to one of the background image

Tags: css

```
background: url('./images/pattern.png'), linear-gradient(to bottom right, rgb(62,131,255), rgb(64,126,253), rgb(99,22,203), rgb(122,5,240));
```

this is the above code where I want to apply opacity to the png image only and not the linear-gradient colour. Is it possible to do so?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `::after` pseudo-element.

```
div#bg {
    /* Assuming other properties are set */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom right, rgb(62,131,255), rgb(64,126,253), rgb(99,22,203), rgb(122,5,240));
}

div#bg::after {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: url('./images/pattern.png');
    opacity: 0.5;
}
```

[Working example.](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/EbMzNY)

Read about [CSS pesudo-element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-elements).

Comment: I'm sorry, this didn't help.

Comment: I showed you a working example. If it didn't help in your case, then something else is wrong in your codebase. Feel free to post more of your code here or consider finding out the problem yourself first. All we have is your one-liner code.

Comment: https://scotch.io/tutorials/how-to-change-a-css-background-images-opacity  - could u plz check this website, this could explain my requirement better. The section that contains "How to Change a CSS Background Image’s Opacity" has a background images of clock, hand,etc. Those are png images with black outlines, but in the website - it's grayed out

Comment: with all due respect, @ArchitaSundaray, it is using exactly my solution above. Take a look at its `header.article__header` "Pseudo ::before element" using browser console.

Comment: Yong Quan - thanku for helping me this far, I was busy yesterday so I'm sorry that I couldn't respond. Here's the link -
 https://github.com/Archiie/patternOpacity . Could you plz look into it and fix the bug? Thanku in advance

Comment: thanku Yong Quan, your code is working - the problem was I didn't understand the concept so was unable to implement it properly, but now it's working fine. :)